# How do I read request header without Express

Tags: node.js, request

Simply, I have a function that gets the weather using request library. I want to see my request header but all the topics I looked at used with Express. How can I do this ?

```
const request = require('request');
function getDegree(cityURL){
request.get({ 
    url:cityURL
    }, (err, res, body)=>{
    if (err) console.log(err);

//My standart codes

console.log(temps); 

//I want console.log(requestHeader) or something like this here, for example.

})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the request headers by storing it inside a variable (`myRequest`), then use `myRequest.headers`.

```js
const request = require("request");

var myRequest = request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
  console.log(requestHeaders);
});

var requestHeaders = myRequest.headers;
```

Comment: I think it is a response header, I need request header (host, user-agent etc.)

Comment: @genzowakabayashi I'm so sorry, it's fixed now 